# How can I place what I want where I want?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I  get the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons to touch the bottom part of the window? I've tried using css, but couldn't do it.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.preview_area = qtw.QWidget()
        self.preview_area.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.preview_area.layout().setContentsMargins(10,10,0,10)

        preview_title = qtw.QLabel("Preview")
        self.preview_area.layout().addWidget(preview_title)

        self.preview = qtw.QLabel(alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.preview.setFixedSize(320, 200)
        self.pixmap = qtg.QPixmap('temp.png')
        self.pixmap.scaled(
            300, 300, qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, qtc.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        self.preview.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        self.buttons = qtw.QWidget()
        self.buttons.setLayout(qtw.QHBoxLayout())
        self.buttons.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.buttons.layout().setSpacing(5)
        self.buttons.layout().addWidget(qtw.QPushButton("OK"))
        self.buttons.layout().addWidget(
            qtw.QPushButton("Cancel")
        )

        self.preview_area.layout().addWidget(self.preview)
        self.preview_area.layout().addWidget(self.buttons)
    
        self.setCentralWidget(self.preview_area)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.preview_area.layout().setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 0)
```

sets the *bottom* margin to zero. You're now setting the right margin. That brings the buttons closer to the window edge.

Curiously enough, whether or not the window has a stylesheet applied at all sets how snugly the buttons are laid out:

No stylesheet (macOS 10.15):

[image]

White background set with a stylesheet

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
```

[image]

Comment: The result of the second image is because setting a generic rule on a parent often has complex consequences on all its children, and this is specifically valid for styles that use pixmaps or rely on the platform plugin to draw primitive elements: setting a basic property automatically overrides the style behavior by falling back to the basic QCommonStyle painting. This is also a problem for complex widgets with children, especially with scroll areas, which results in the scroll bars not respecting the current style. For this reason is *very* important to *not* set such generic painting rules.

Comment: Selectors should always be preferred when setting stylesheets on widget that can have children. In this case, if the wanted result is to set the background of the top level window, the solution is to use the class name `MainWindow { background-color: white; }`, the inherited class name (QMainWindow) or, alternatively, the top level selector: `:window { background: white; }` (with or without the class). If the result should be to change the default background color, then the proper solution is to set the QApplication palette using the `Window` color role (and, eventually, the `Button` role).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the comments! I'm no Qt person, so I'm sure I did the stylesheet wrong (as you pointed out), but the fact that setting a stylesheet at all makes the layout snugger is strange, if not unexpected! :)

Comment: I agree it's a bit counterintuitive, but it's a limitation by design (not well documented, unfortunately): due to the complex implementation of both platform theme plugins and the private QStyleSheetStyle, it's almost impossible to provide a compatible system that works for advanced (and difficult to work with) styles, if not at the cost of performance. The layout is changed indirectly by the pixel metrics of the fallback QCommonStyle buttons. That said, setting a general `background` rule wouldn't be very smart for standard CSS too, so using selectors is not a "workaround", but good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the central widget bottom margin. So change `self.preview_area.layout().setContentsMargins(10,10,0,10)` to `self.preview_area.layout().setContentsMargins(10,10,0,0)`.